# Handling unicode on GAE Golang blobstore

Tags: google-app-engine, unicode, go

I'm trying to upload image to `Google App Engine blobstore`.
Besides of file field, I have some other fields in the form (such as article title, content...).

I'm using the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14937952/2470021), it's working fine except error with `unicode` for those other fields.

For example, `"こんにちは"` become `"$B$3$s$K$A$O(B"` when storing to datastore. What is the workaround for this issue?

**Updated**

Below is my code

```
   func handleSave(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      c := appengine.NewContext(r)
      blobs, other_fields, err := blobstore.ParseUpload(r)
      if err != nil {
        serveError(c, w, err)
        return
      }

      id := other_fields["id"][0]
      categoryId, _ := strconv.ParseInt(other_fields["category_id"][0], 10, 64)
      title := string(other_fields["title"][0])
      content := []byte(other_fields["content"][0])

      image := blobs["file"]
      // ...
    }
```

Comment: you can transfer unicode to UTF8, then store.

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: Maybe store content as either string or []rune, does that help?

Comment: @OneOfOne The `title` field is string but still faces the issue. Strange thing is everything is working fine on development environment. I tried with []rune but it didn't help, could you tell more detail about []rune solution?
@Jerry YY Rain Could you show some sample code :-). I'm new to Golang.

Comment: @JohnnyLe RE "everything is working fine on development environment": do you use the same browser on production? Is it possible that the extra multipart form fields are not UTF-8 encoded? Since your example is Hiragana, maybe it is encoded differently. Try looking at all request headers, and also the individual multipart headers.

Comment: @AttilaO. I use the same browser on both environments. I've looked at the headers, all are fine. I think it's about binary data encoding, but because it takes me time, for now I decided to separate the image uploader from other contents.