# Handle image and text upload in Go in Google App Engine

Tags: file, google-app-engine, post, go

I'm following this guide on how to handle file upload in Go: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/blobstore/

Scroll down to 'Complete Sample Application' to see the whole code.

I'm trying to handle a POST request with both an image file and some text, but I can't seem to get it working. I want to save the image in Blobstore and I want to save the text in my own struct as its own type called "Item".

Here's my code:

```
func handleUpload(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)
  blobs, _, err := blobstore.ParseUpload(r)
  if err != nil {
    serveError(ctx, w, err)
    return
  }
  file := blobs["file"]
  if len(file) == 0 {
    log.Errorf(ctx, "no file uploaded")
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusFound)
    return
  }

  var n string = r.FormValue("name")
  lat, errLat := strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("latitude"), 64)
  long, errLong := strconv.ParseFloat(r.FormValue("longitude"), 64)

  if errLat != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Invalid latitude format: " + errLat.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
  }

  if errLong != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Invalid longitude format: " + errLong.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
  }

  c := appengine.NewContext(r)
  g := Item { Name: n, Date: time.Now(), Latitude: lat, Longitude: long, ImageKey: string(file[0].BlobKey)}
  // We set the same parent key on every Greeting entity to ensure each Greeting
  // is in the same entity group. Queries across the single entity group
  // will be consistent. However, the write rate to a single entity group
  // should be limited to ~1/second.
  key := datastore.NewIncompleteKey(c, "Item", itemKey(c))
  _, err = datastore.Put(c, key, &g)
  if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
  }

  http.Redirect(w, r, "/serve/?blobKey="+string(file[0].BlobKey), http.StatusFound)
}
```

When I get down to retrieve the text from the post in

```
var n string = r.FormValue("name")
```

The text is empty because it has already been used in the request to save the image. I know that a request can only be "used" once.

My question is: Am I approaching this the wrong way? How would you grab both text and image out of a POST request in Go?

Here's the HTML form:

```
<html>
    <body>
       <form action="{{.}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Name: <br>
            <div><textarea name="name" rows="1" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            Latitude: <br>
            <div><textarea name="latitude" rows="1" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            longitude: <br>
            <div><textarea name="longitude" rows="1" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your HTML `<form>`.

Comment: Added the HTML <form>

Comment: And by the way, the image is saved successfully in the Blobstore.

Comment: @PæturMagnussen  did you saw this question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/14937952/817571

Comment: Perfect! That solved my problem. Thanks a lot, @MlkCode